# Selenium how to get browser instance count

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How do we get the currently running Chrome browser instance count?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Since there is limitation on maximum instance count in Chrome, I need to get the current instance count before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this would be the same as the number of window handles you have, so try with `len(driver.window_handles)`